# How do I get the full path of my firebase storage item? (including the gs://)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

## My Issue

I'd like to have the full url such as:

`gs://my-app-name.appspot.com/companies/666d236f-a075-492d-8110-a3f4bd6d7f18/logo`

## My Solution

I'm using the response from uploading to build the url like this:

```js
const res = await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
const gsPath = `gs://${res.ref.bucket}/${res.ref.fullPath}`
```

## My Question

I looked the docs but didn't find any method or property to get the full url without constructing it myself. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To  get the full url there is a method `toString`:

in your case :

```js
const gsPath = res.ref.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getDownloadURL() method.
[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files)

final fb_storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
return await fb_storage.ref().child("ImageCollectionName").child("ImageID").getDownloadURL();

Comment: that gives me an http url. I'm trying to get the gs:// link. how can I do that without manuel construction? thx!

Comment: I haven't had the need to use the GS link directly. But in any case you can write a function in a class which could return the required GS link as per your code and then you can call it from anywhere after importing to get the GS url.